# Kasparov trying to poison Kamsky

Tags: kasparov

Did the mature Gata Kamsky ever try to explain the accusations against Kasparov in the early 1990s about Kasparov trying to poison him? I remember at least a couple interviews in New in Chess magazine where the accusations were made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know for sure, but my guess is that those accusations largely came from Kamsky's father, who was quite belligerent at the time.  In later intereviews, Kamsky tended to avoid discussing his father and that period in his career, so I doubt it has been revisited.